Python module with name __main__.py doesn't run while imported
Somebody asked me a question and I honestly didn't try it before, So it was interesting to know what exactly happens when we name a module __main__.py. So I named a module __main__.py, imported it in another file with name test.py. Surprisingly when I tried to run test.py it prints nothing and none of the functions of __main__.py are available in test.py. Here is the contents of these files :
Here is the contents of __main__.py :
def add(a,b):
    result = a+b
    return result

print(__name__)

if __name__=='__main__':
    print(add(1,2))

Here is the contents of test.py :
import __main__

Why isn't the print statement from __main__.py reached? Although when I rename the __main__.py with some other name such as func.py, the program runs correctly and the line that prints module's name works fine.

@Friedrich I don't know calling a question Fascinating abuse of the language is a good way of treating questions. Sometimes people learn from their mistakes and their curiosities. The question is clearly asked.

@wim Thanks for mentioning it, You are right. I'm gonna update my question.

If nothing else, __main__.py isn't meant to be imported explicitly; if foo/__main__.py exists, it's what gets executed when you use python -m foo.

Funny that my comment which was intended to express some admiration for a creative way of using Python beyond its intended usage caused offense. I apologize for the misunderstanding. Well, somebody deleted it so all is fine I guess.

When you run python test.py, the test.py module itself is already present in sys.modules with the key "__main__" (see top-level code environment in the docs). The import __main__ will just return this existing cache hit, so the presence of a __main__.py file on sys.path is irrelevant.
These modifications to test.py will prove that point:
import sys
print(sys.modules['__main__'])  # it's already in there before the import
import __main__
print(__main__.__file__)  # this should be the abspath of test.py


Thanks, The code helps me to understand it really well.

So, what is happening is that when you do import __main__, it is first searching for already imported modules, and finding the entrypoint (i.e. test.py) in sys.modules['__main__'], so it simply returns that result.
Note, this is why if __name__ == "__main__": works as a guard.

Thanks, I did know this is the reason why __name__ == '__main__' works, I wanted to know the implementation details of it. Which you explained it really good. Thanks.
